# How to convert a textView text into a char variable?

Tags: java, android, textview, char

So I'm trying to convert a Edittext text that will be entered by the user into a char variable, but i can't seem to make it work. Also, didn't manage find anything useful so decided to just ask in here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, a string is an array of chars. You can use `text.charAt(0)` to get the first char from the string. But you cannot just convert any string to a char (as the string could contain more than one char).

Comment: You are probably confusing between types. `char` is one thing, `string` is aonther. You probably want a string out of a TextView, not a single character.

Answer (score 1):

Make `EditText` something like this

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLength="1" />
```

It will only take single character from User. Now you can convert in String something like this :

Code with Example :

```
Edittext et = (Edittext) findViewById(R.id.et1); // This will take Edittext of You're layout
String value = et.getText().toString(); // Get User input String
Character char = value.charAt(0); // Character
```

As per you're question.

Remove the Max Length.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Code :

```
Edittext et = (Edittext) findViewById(R.id.et1); // This will take Edittext of You're layout
String value = et.getText().toString(); // Get User input String
for(int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++){
    Log.d("Char", value.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: And what if the edit text had to take 2 characters instead of 1?

Comment: As per question character contain only 1 letter. So if user try to insert 2 character it won't work either. You have to pass full string and apply logic to get proper output.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a char from a `String` using `str.getCharAt(index)`. Here `index` is the index of the character of the string that you want.
Also you can't change a `String` into a char but you can change the `String` into a `array` of chars.

```
String str = textView.getText().toString();
char[] chr = str.toCharArray();
```

Further, you can get any character from the array with the index of that character.

```
char c = chr[i]; // i is the index such as 0,1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned by @mumpitz you could use `text.charAt(0)` if you need only a single character.
Or if you need the whole string you could use `text.toCharArray()` which will give you an array of chars.